# ライブラリOnboard、スキップで画面遷移時 クラッシュ

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3

Onboardライブラリのスキップハンドラーで画面遷移しようとするとエラーがでます。
クリーンとビルドも何度か試しました。原因が分かりません。

Swift3.0
Onboard　v2.3.1 
Xcode 8.1

エラーメッセージ

> skip 2016-12-07 08:09:10.700 OnboardTestEX[2975:60144] *** Terminating
>
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>
>   'Receiver () has no
>
>   segue with identifier 'SegueIdentifier''
>
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7bf34b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib   
>
>   0x0000000107d1a21e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   UIKit               
>
>   0x000000010838db6b -[UIViewController
>
>   shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0     3   OnboardTestEX      
>
>   0x0000000107712c72
>
>   _TFFC13OnboardTestEX14ViewControllercFT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0__U3_FT_T_
>
>   + 450     4   OnboardTestEX                       0x0000000107712761 _TTRXFo___XFo_iT__iT** + 17  5   OnboardTestEX                       0x0000000107712dd1 _TPA__TTRXFo___XFo_iT__iT__.19 + 81  6  
>   OnboardTestEX                       0x0000000107712e00
>   _TTRXFo_iT__iT__XFo___ + 32   7   OnboardTestEX                       0x0000000107712eb7 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 39  8   Onboard               
>   0x00000001077bf0c8 -[OnboardingViewController handleSkipButtonPressed]
>   + 120     9   UIKit                               0x00000001081eb5b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83   10  UIKit                               0x0000000108370edd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67    11 
>   UIKit                               0x00000001083711f6 -[UIControl
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444   12  UIKit                               0x00000001083700f2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668   13 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000108258ce1 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747     14  UIKit                               0x000000010825a3cf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011    15  UIKit           
>   0x000000010820763f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371  16  UIKit       
>   0x00000001089f971d **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>
>     17  UIKit                               0x00000001089f23c7
>
>   __handleEventQueue + 4879     18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a764311
>
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a74959c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a748a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918     21  CoreFoundation           
>   0x000000010a748494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     22  GraphicsServices   
>   0x000000010e695a6f GSEventRunModal + 161  23  UIKit                   
>   0x00000001081e9964 UIApplicationMain + 159    24  OnboardTestEX         
>   0x000000010771521f main + 111     25  libdyld.dylib                      
>   0x000000010c43f68d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

以下ソースです。skipHandlerの中にperformSegueがあります。

```
import UIKit
import Onboard


class ViewController: OnboardingViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let welcomePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "PAY WHAT YOU WANT", body: "I made my app so you could have the best experience reading tech related news. That’s why I want you to value it based on your satisfaction.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Pig"), buttonText: "") {}
        let firstPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "MINT", body: "The app is great but there’s still a few places in room of improvement. If this is your feeling this is for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Mint"), buttonText: "69p") {}
        let secondPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "SWEET", body: "IThis is the suggested price where you value the time I spent on development and design. Feel free to pay more or less.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Lolly"), buttonText: "£1.49") {}
        let thirdPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "GOLD", body: "Hello is it me your looking for, if this popped into your mind using the app then this is the price for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Gold"), buttonText: "£2.99") {}

        super.init(backgroundImage: nil, contents: [welcomePage, firstPurchasePage, secondPurchasePage, thirdPurchasePage])

        // Customize Onboard viewController
        allowSkipping = true
        skipHandler = { _ in
            print("skip")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
}
```

[image: メインストーリーボード]
[image: ViewController]

ーーーーーー
以下のようにして、ストーリーボードのセグエは使わないようにしたら遷移出来ました。

let storyboard: UIStoryboard = self.storyboard!
        let nextView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "next") as! NextViewController
        self.present(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard/issues/150　　　　　　　　　　　　ここを見てOnboard　v2.3.1 を使えばクラッシュしないと思っていましたが、詳しい方いらっしゃれば教えて下さい・。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    // 略

    super.init(backgroundImage: nil, contents: [welcomePage, firstPurchasePage, secondPurchasePage, thirdPurchasePage])

    // 略
}
```

このイニシアライザは、

```
super.init(coder aDecoder)
```

で、スーパークラスのイニシアライザを呼ばなければいけないのではないでしょうか？となると、`contents`の初期化はどうするのか？という問題になり、つまるところ、Onboardというライブラリが、Storyboardでインスタンスを生成することを、考慮しておらず、コードからインスタンスを生成することが前提になっているということだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。